# Node not responding in ubuntu?

Tags: debugging, node.js

I have installed nodejs on ubuntu.

```
username@username-VirtualBox:~$ cd node
username@username-VirtualBox:~/node$ node app.js
```

If I made a mistake in my code then it's respond me about the error but when my code is working code it's not respond me anything. Like people have shown that "running on 127.0.0.1230".

How I can got it worked.

Comment: Did you setup your Virtual Box networking to alllow host-guest communication?

Comment: I have not setup anything. Let me know how to do it.

Comment: Examine these: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Comment: app.js is my file where I have write my code. it's doesn't show me anything in the case when it's should run.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an app.js that will show `running on 127.0.0.1230`:

```
console.log( 'running on 127.0.0.1230' );
```

When you run it like this: `node app.js`, you get `running on 127.0.0.1230`.

`console.log` logs something to the console.

Comment: I have tried to run console.log(' I am running on '+ process.env.PORT); and got in terminal  I am running on undefined

Comment: Using express, you can get the port through `app.address().port`, assuming your express object is in the `app` object.